# Let Scrapy continue to crawl from last break point

Tags: scrapy

I'm using scrapy to crawl an website, but bad thing happens (power down, etc.).

I wonder how can I continue my crawling from where it was broke. I don't want to start over from the seeds.

Answer (score 5):

This can be done by persisting scheduled requests to the disk.

```
scrapy crawl somespider -s JOBDIR=crawls/somespider-1
```

See http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/jobs.html for more information.

Comment: by the doc: "by pressing Ctrl-C or sending a signal". so it wont work if (power down, etc.) it is just for you to pausing I think.